# Exchange Web Service (EWS) & CLR on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, clr, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use the microsoft Exchange Web Service (EWS) API on SQL Server 2012 using CLR. I've been able to develop a DLL and test app that works great on my development machine, but fails to initialize the ExchangeService object when the assembly is registered on the database. Through trial and error i was able to get the microsoft.exchange.webservices assembly to register by copying the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll on the SQL server using this line:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [microsoft.exchange.webservices] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

I got the idea from [here](http://www.redmars.com.au/blog/itsupport/database/sql2005/385).

I can get my CLR assembly to register on the server, but when I run the code, I get and error on this line:

```
returnValue = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
```

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal
>   form.

I'm using VB.NET code in Visual Studio 2010. The EWS version is 2.2 (v2.0.50727).

I've tried compiling my DLL targeting the 3.5 and 4.0 (i have 4.5 installed) frameworks, targeting the AnyCPU, x86, and x64 CPU, all to no avail. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: The constructor for ExchangeService is looking for the version of the DLL for Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. It is expecting ExchangeService to be instantiated from a file DLL so it can check the version on the file.  In your case the constructor cannot locate the file the DLL was instantiated from, and so you are seeing this error.  I am having a similar issue.